# How can I alter the values of a variable with onclick multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a JS newbie, recently I found an SDK for creating augmented reality apps with html/css/js called wikitude. When you see below, you'll see a button that when clicked calls the scaleModel function which then creates new values for the scale property which will allow the 3d model my app displays increase in size. I'd just like to be able to create a button that will increase the value each time I press it and the another button that will decrease the value each time I press it. This way I will have two buttons, one for increasing the size and another for decreasing. I would very much so appreciate your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width = 540, user-scalable = 0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My ARchitect World</title>
<script src="architect://architect.js"></script>
<script>
var model;
var location;

function createModel()
{
AR.logger.activateDebugMode();
AR.logger.info("info");

var modelOptions = {
    scale: {x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1},
    rotate: {heading: -30},
    rotate: {tilt: 30},
    translate: {y: -0.5}
};

model = new AR.Model("my3dModel.wt3", modelOptions);
location = new AR.RelativeLocation(null, 0, -50, 0);
var myGeoObject = new AR.GeoObject(location, {drawables: {cam: model}});
}

function scaleModel() {
model.scale.x = 0.5;
model.scale.y = 0.5;
model.scale.z = 0.5;
}

</script>
</head>
```

Create Anim
Scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a new function like the `scaleModel()` function that multiplies the scale by an amount instead of setting it:

```
function scaleModelBy(amount) {
    model.scale.x = model.scale.x * amount;
    model.scale.y = model.scale.y * amount;
    model.scale.z = model.scale.z * amount;
}
```

You can then call it in some buttons:

```
<button onclick="scaleModelBy(2);">Scale up</button>
<button onclick="scaleModelBy(0.5);">Scale down</button>
```

Comment: My only option is to multiple? I can't add? multiplying will not allow me to scale as precise as I'd like.

Comment: You can add. Just make another function or modify the function above so that it adds the amount instead of multiplying.

Comment: Don't they both have to be float

Comment: In JavaScript, numbers are just `Number`s. All `Number`s are floating point. You can write `2` and `2.0` and they mean exactly the same thing. You do not have to worry about `int`s and `float`s.

Comment: so model.scale.x = model.scale.x + amount; ? that's it?

Comment: That will do it, yep. Give it a go and see!